# How to remove the DATE TIME that have NAN vaules

Tags: python-2.7, date, datetime, pandas

How do I remove the DATE and TIMEs with the NAN value in the 'oo' column.

this is my csv

DATE,TIME,OPEN,HIGH,LOW,CLOSE,VOLUME
02/03/1997,09:04:00,3046.00,3048.50,3046.00,3047.50,505
02/03/1997,09:05:00,3047.00,3048.00,3046.00,3047.00,162
02/03/1997,09:06:00,3047.50,3048.00,3047.00,3047.50,98
02/03/1997,09:07:00,3047.50,3047.50,3047.00,3047.50,228
02/03/1997,09:08:00,3048.00,3048.00,3047.50,3048.00,136
02/03/1997,09:09:00,3048.00,3048.00,3046.50,3046.50,174
02/03/1997,09:10:00,3046.50,3046.50,3045.00,3045.00,134
02/03/1997,09:11:00,3045.50,3046.00,3044.00,3045.00,43
02/03/1997,09:12:00,3045.00,3045.50,3045.00,3045.00,214
02/03/1997,09:13:00,3045.50,3045.50,3045.50,3045.50,8
02/03/1997,09:14:00,3045.50,3046.00,3044.50,3044.50,152
02/03/1997,09:15:00,3044.00,3044.00,3042.50,3042.50,126
02/03/1997,09:16:00,3043.50,3043.50,3043.00,3043.00,128
02/03/1997,09:17:00,3042.50,3043.50,3042.50,3043.50,23
02/03/1997,09:18:00,3043.50,3044.50,3043.00,3044.00,51
02/03/1997,09:19:00,3044.50,3044.50,3043.00,3043.00,18
02/03/1997,09:20:00,3043.00,3045.00,3043.00,3045.00,23
02/03/1997,09:21:00,3045.00,3045.00,3044.50,3045.00,51
02/03/1997,09:22:00,3045.00,3045.00,3045.00,3045.00,47
02/03/1997,09:23:00,3045.50,3046.00,3045.00,3045.00,77
02/03/1997,09:24:00,3045.00,3045.00,3045.00,3045.00,131
02/03/1997,09:25:00,3044.50,3044.50,3043.50,3043.50,138
02/03/1997,09:26:00,3043.50,3043.50,3043.50,3043.50,6
02/03/1997,09:27:00,3043.50,3043.50,3043.00,3043.00,56
02/03/1997,09:28:00,3043.00,3044.00,3043.00,3044.00,32
02/03/1997,09:29:00,3044.50,3044.50,3044.50,3044.50,63
02/03/1997,09:30:00,3045.00,3045.00,3045.00,3045.00,28

here's my code.

```
exp = pd.read_csv('example.txt', parse_dates = [["DATE", "TIME"]], index_col=0)

exp['oo'] = opcl.OPEN.resample("5Min").first() 
print exp['oo']
```

and I get this

```
 DATE_TIME
 1997-02-03 09:04:00       NaN
 1997-02-03 09:05:00    3047.0
 1997-02-03 09:06:00       NaN
 1997-02-03 09:07:00       NaN
 1997-02-03 09:08:00       NaN
 1997-02-03 09:09:00       NaN
 1997-02-03 09:10:00    3046.5
```

I want to get rid of all the DATE_TIME rows with NaN vaules in the 'oo' column.
I've tried.

```
  exp['oo'] = exp['oo'].dropna()
```

But I get the same thing.
I've looked all threw the http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/missing_data.html

And looked all over this website.

I would like to keep my csv reader the same but idk.

If anybody could help it would be greatly appreciated thanks so much for your time.

Comment: `opcl` above is not defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want this:

```
>>> exp.OPEN.resample("5Min", how='first')

DATE_TIME
1997-02-03 09:00:00    3046.0
1997-02-03 09:05:00    3047.0
1997-02-03 09:10:00    3046.5
1997-02-03 09:15:00    3044.0
1997-02-03 09:20:00    3043.0
1997-02-03 09:25:00    3044.5
1997-02-03 09:30:00    3045.0
Freq: 5T, Name: OPEN, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Some reason when I do that I still get all the NaN's

Comment: Which version of Pandas are you using?  `pd.__version__`

Comment: Works fine for me using 0.18.0 with this sample data above.  Can you replicate? What is `exp.shape`?  It should be (27, 5).

Comment: 74, (just extra type to comment)

Comment: Are you parsing the data correctly?  What is `pd.read_csv(...).shape`?

Comment: I don't think so? I got a (74,5)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110692/discussion-between-alexander-and-sam-c21).